# Write a single xpath to check whether several rows(td) have specific values

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I  am running ROBOT Framework with Selenium2Library.
I have a table with several columns. I want to locate which row in this table has specific text/output that I want. For this case, I am interested with column 2,3,4,5 and 6 as shown below. The question here is how do I make this xpath as a single xpath query? In this case, there are many rows(tr) in this table.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  ...
  <td></td> # column 2 must have this output ->'ROUTE A'
  <td></td> # column 3 must have this output ->'ROUTE B'
  <td></td> # column 4 must have this output ->'Intermediate'
  <td></td> # column 5 must have this output ->'Sent'
  <td></td> # column 6 must have this output ->'No'
 <tr>..</tr>
 <tr>..</tr>
 ...
```

Comment: You are not asking about a specific problem, unfortunately we are not here to do work for you. As far as getting those elements I would recommend using a [CSS selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) instead which I feel would be easier than XPath for this case. Then loop through the results and compare to string values. Try it first then post a question when you have a specific issue.

Comment: My apology if the question was not clear enough. I was asking on how to write an xpath in a single line. I prefer XPATH than css for now. However, the answer below really works for me. Thanks all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This xpath query can be written in a single line as below..

```
//table/tbody/tr[(td[2]='ROUTE A') and (td[3]='ROUTE B') and (td[4]='Intermediate') and (td[5]='Sent') and (td[6]='No')]
```

To write in ROBOT Framework:

```
WAIT UNTIL PAGE CONTAINS ELEMENT    xpath=//table/tbody/tr[(td[2]='ROUTE A') and (td[3]='ROUTE B') and (td[4]='Intermediate') and (td[5]='Sent') and (td[6]='No')]
```

OR we can assign the result(boolean) in a variable like below..

```
${found}= RUN KEYWORD AND RETURN STATUS     WAIT UNTIL PAGE CONTAINS ELEMENT    xpath=//table/tbody/tr[(td[2]='ROUTE A') and (td[3]='ROUTE B') and (td[4]='Intermediate') and (td[5]='Sent') and (td[6]='No')]
```